# XSLT convert text/special characters to HTML

Tags: xslt

In my XML file I have the following node with text content that is HTML encoded for reserved characters:

```
<seg>&lt;div style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;padding-top:10px;height:0;overflow:hidden;"&gt;&lt;iframe src="https://www.example.com/video/fmsh/embed.1/subject.27453" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height: 100%;" width="550" height="306" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</seg>
```

I want to process the content of `<seg>` back into HTML using XSLT 3.0 (under eXist-db) during the transformation process. In Xquery (also under eXist-db) I can use `util:parse()` to do this, but I have been unable to identify the same functionality in XSLT. I feel as though `xsl:result-document` should be the tool but I haven't come close to even getting it to output a useable error to find a solution, so I'm not sure that is even the correct approach.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Adding two attempts:

1.

```
<xsl:template match="seg">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

outputs:

```
<?javax.xml.transform.disable-output-escaping?>&lt;div style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;padding-top:10px;height:0;overflow:hidden;"&gt;&lt;iframe src="https://www.example.com/video/fmsh/embed.1/subject.27453" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height: 100%;" width="550" height="306" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/div&gt;<?javax.xml.transform.enable-output-escaping?>
```

2.

```
<xsl:template match="seg">
    <xsl:value-of select="parse-xml-fragment(./text())"/>
</xsl:template>
```

outputs: nothing

Comment: `parse-xml-fragment` should work (provided the input is a well-formed XML fragment) and so should `disable-output-escaping` (provided your processor supports it and is the one doing the serialization) - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCS8

Comment: Ah, `parse-xml-fragment()` didn't work because I used `value-of` not `copy-of`. Now it works perfect!

Comment: Ha! I should have spotted this in your attempt, since I made the same mistake initially...

Answer (score 1):

To transform the content of your `<seg>` element to HTML, you can simply use the (optional) attribute [`disable-output-escaping` of `xsl:value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d-o-e-in-data-model):

```
<xsl:value-of select="seg" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

It is not supported by all XSLT processors, so try it out.
The output of this is HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;padding-top:10px;height:0;overflow:hidden;"><iframe src="https://www.example.com/video/fmsh/embed.1/subject.27453?width=100%&height=100%" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height: 100%;" width="550" height="306" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

You cannot easily process this output further with an XSLT processor, because it's not *well-formed* XML (it's HTML):

1. There is an unescaped `&` in the `@src` attribute
2. The HTML attribute `allowfullscreen` has no value (not acceptable in XML)

---

But if you really want to process it further, treat the result as a string, replace the problematic aspects with the `fn:replace()` function, and then use the `fn:parse-xml-fragment()` function to output conforming XML.

Comment: I tried the two solutions, and I have posted the XSLT and the results at the end of my original question (after cleaning up the HTML to make it well-formed XML). Unfortunately neither outputs the HTML correctly....

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: not all XSLT processors do support `disable-output-escaping`. It seems that yours doesn't support it. What's the name of your XSLT processor?

Comment: I am using eXist-db which hands off XSLT transformation to Saxon. But after some research it seems Saxon only supports `disable-output-escaping` when it also does the serialization.

Comment: Another approach with Saxon is to use the extension function saxon:parse-html(). Requires Saxon-PE or higher.

Comment: @MichaelKay I did see that, but unfortunately our eXist install and web app does not have access to Saxon-PE + as we are a French humanities university research center...thus depend on open source and free academic licenses.